# OctoberCMS Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I use octobercms and User Extended plugin(Clacke). I try to render a pagination because for now i have a lot of registered users and they display on one page.

I use random users function from ***\classes\UserManager.php***

```
public static function getRandomUserSet($limit = 7)
{
    $returner = new Collection;

    $userCount = User::all()->count();

    if(!isset($userCount) || empty($userCount) || $userCount == 0)
        return [];

    if($userCount < $limit)
        $limit = $userCount;

    $users = User::all(); //paginate(5)

    if(empty($users))
        return $returner;

    $users->random($limit);

    $friends = FriendsManager::getAllFriends();

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $userAdd = true;

        if(!$friends->isEmpty())
        {
            foreach($friends as $friend)
            {
                if($user->id == $friend->id)
                {
                    $userAdd = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if($user->id == UserUtil::getLoggedInUser()->id)
            $userAdd = false;

        if($userAdd)
        {
            $returner->push($user);
        }
    }

    return $returner->shuffle();


}
```

try to do this with changing        `return $returner->paginate(25);`  and `$users = User::paginate(25);`  but throws me an error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
> ("Method paginate does not exist.").

After that i try to change directly in ***\components\User.php***

```
public function randomUsers()
    {


        return UserManager::getRandomUserSet($this->property('maxItems'))->paginate(12);


    }
```

But again the same error.

Tryed and with this code and render in **default.htm** `{{ tests.render|raw }}`

```
public function randomUsers()
    {

$test = UserManager::getRandomUserSet($this->property('maxItems'));
        
return $test->paginate(10);

    }
```

Again with no success. Could anyoune give me some navigation and help to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `random users function from \classes\UserManager.php`

I checked the code and found that its using `Illuminate\Support\Collection` Object. So, for that `Collection Object` pagination works differently

You need to use `forPage` method.

On the other hands `paginate` is method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` <- so both collection are not same

> Use `forpage`

```
// OLD return UserManager::getRandomUserSet($this->property('maxItems'))
//         ->paginate(12);

TO 

return UserManager::getRandomUserSet($this->property('maxItems'))
           ->forPage(1, 12);
```

> `forPage` method works like `forPage(<<PAGE_NO>>, <<NO_OF_ITEM_PER_PAGE>>)`;

so if you use `forPage` it will work fine.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: How can I render (dispaly) pagination (page numbers) on **default.html**?

Here is the user displaying
[CODE LINK](https://pastebin.com/0w5xbnye)

Comment: hmm then you need more data like the actual number of items in `randomUser collection` then device it by item_per_page and you get a total page, based on that you can loop and show pages, on click of the page you can pass page no. and again use that page no. in `forPage` argument
- but I guess you need to do it client-side in JS because if you make a PHP request it will give you new random users that are different from previous